# IllegalStateException on camel cxf route in FUSE (servicemix) ESB

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I try to set up a camel (Ver. 2.4.0) route in a FUSE (Ver. 4.3.0) ESB/OSGi container.
It should be a simple cxf-proxy to route a WebService call from a 'proxy' address to a real service.

I read several documentation:

- [CXF Proxy Example](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html)
- [camel cxf component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

and set up the following spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi/camel-osgi.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <import
        resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import
        resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import
        resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" />
    <import
        resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/osgi/cxf-extension-osgi.xml" />

    <!-- the proxy service -->
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        id="myServiceProxy"
        address="http://localhost:9003/cxf/myService"
        serviceClass="foo.bar.iface.MyServiceInterface" />

    <!-- my real existing cxf soap service -->
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        id="myService"
        address="http://foo.bar/services/myService"
        wsdlURL="http://foo.bar/services/myService?wsdl"
        serviceClass="foo.bar.iface.MyServiceInterface"
        serviceName="s:MyService"
        endpointName="s:MyServiceEndpoint"
        xmlns:s="http://foo.bar/iface/" />

    <!-- route -->
    <camel:camelContext>
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from
                uri="cxf:bean:myServiceProxy" />
            <camel:to
                uri="cxf:bean:myService" />
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>

</beans>
```

Trying to start the bundle in FUSE leads to this exception

```
karaf@root> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-22" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Endpoint address should be a relative URI wrt to the servlet address (use '/xxx' for example)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1126)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:103)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:231)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
```

I do not know what's wrong. I doubt that my Endpoint address is wrong and I do not know what my servlet address is (there is no cxf:cxfEndoint servelt address attribute).

Any help to lead me in the right direction to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks
  Klaus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what's wrong.

Instead

```
<!-- the proxy service -->
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
    id="myServiceProxy"
    address="http://localhost:9003/cxf/myService"
    serviceClass="foo.bar.iface.MyServiceInterface" />
```

it has to be

```
<!-- the proxy service -->
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
    id="myServiceProxy"
    address="/myService"
    serviceClass="foo.bar.iface.MyServiceInterface" />
```

As the first approach worked well running the camel project outside FUSE (in this case a the http server will be started to provide the service) it has to be a relative address inside FUSE.

Inside FUSE the embedded HTTP server which runs on (localhost:8181) will be used and the service url will be extended to `http://localhost:8181/cxf/myService`.